# Send / receive data over network in C

Tags: c, network-programming

I have written this program:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int socket_desc;
struct sockaddr_in adress;
int addrlen;
int new_socket;
int bufsize = 1024;

char *you_sent = "You sent: ";

int main() {
    char *buffer = malloc(bufsize);
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    adress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    adress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    adress.sin_port = htons(7000);
    bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&adress, sizeof(adress));
    listen(socket_desc, 3);
    addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&adress, &addrlen);
    while(recv(new_socket,buffer,bufsize,0))
    {
        printf("I recieved: %s", buffer);
        send(new_socket, you_sent, strlen(you_sent), 0);
        send(new_socket, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0);
        memset(buffer, '\0', sizeof(buffer));
    }
}
```

I can connect to the server with a telnet. And write stuff to the application and recieve data from the application.
But i cannot get my head around how i can connect to this with another c program and send and recieve data from that program.
I have tried this:

```
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int socket_desc;
struct sockaddr_in adress;
int addrlen;
int new_socket;

char *message_to_send = "Hello world!";

int main() {
    socket_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    adress.sin_family = AF_INET;
    adress.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    adress.sin_port = htons(7000);
    bind(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&adress, sizeof(adress));
    listen(socket_desc, 3);
    addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    new_socket = accept(socket_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&adress, &addrlen);
    send(new_socket, message_to_send, strlen(message_to_send), 0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sequence is the following:

**Server side:**

- Socket creation with the `socket` syscall;
- Binding of the port with the `bind` syscall;
- Listening with the `listen` syscall (this will enable the backlog queue);
- Accepting the incoming connections with the `accept` syscall

  - This is a *blocking* operation: your thread will remain blocked until a connection comes in);
  - The `accept` function will return a new *file descriptor* representing the new connection. You will use this one to send/receive data with the other host, while the original *file descriptor* (from `socket`) will be used for new incoming connections.

**Client side:**

- Socket creation with `socket`;
- Connection with `connect`.

[Here](https://man.openbsd.org/Linux-4.13/tcp.7) you may find some additional resources.

Answer (score 5):

A server is like a telephone operator on a switch board. That person does the following:

- Sits in front of a phone (i.e. `bind` to a number)
- Waits for it to ring (i.e. `listen`)
- Picks up the phone (i.e. `accept`)

The person at the other end just wants to make a call to that person. (i.e. `connect`). The person only needs to go to the phone when a call needs to be made. Therefore not bound to the phone or has to listen for it to ring.

I hope this metaphor helps in your understanding.

PS: The `socket` part is the phone socket on the wall.